# How do I record headset mic and headphones at the same time along with video of the computer's screen in Ubuntu 18.04 with LXDE?

Tags: screen

I tried to record a video of the computer's screen along with sound with the app `simplescreenrecorder` while I have a headset connected through bluetooth to the computer. I selected Pulseaudio as backend and the headset as audio source to record audio along with the screen video.

Even though I wanted to record both sound sources, mic and headphones of the headset at the same time, it only recorded the sound of the headphones. Do you know how I could fix this to be able to record both audio sources at the same time along with the video?
Thanks

Comment: Forthat mixing needs you can use `jack` or `audacity`

Comment: Thanks @cmak.fr for the tip. Audacity did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

cmak.fr's comment was helpful.
I then found the following link
[leehblue.com/record-phone-calls-audacity-ubuntu/](https://leehblue.com/record-phone-calls-audacity-ubuntu/)

Even though the explanation of the link above is kind of long, carrying out just the following 2 steps with the settings displayed in attachment worked for me.[image]

1st. Running audacity and clicking on the red round button (Record button).
2nd. Running simplescreenrecorder.
Find in attachments the settings that worked for me.

Comment: I realized later on I do not even need to run audacity. For some reason it is enough to run simplescreenrecorder on a command terminal and to select my bluetooth device as audio input source before clicking on the "start recording" button.